# Conda always opens root environment

Tags: ipython, anaconda, seaborn, conda

If I 'source activate' a non-root environment (in my case "data"), then launch Jupyter notebook, the env seems to switch to root.  I can tell because if I try to open a new python notebook, the dropdown under New says Python [Root].  I am also unable to import packages in my env, but not in root.

```
(data) Edwards-MacBook-Pro:~ mango$ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/mango/anaconda/envs/data:
#
boto                      2.42.0                   py35_0  
bz2file                   0.98                     py35_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0  
freetype                  2.5.5                         1  
gensim                    0.12.4              np111py35_0  
libpng                    1.6.22                        0  
matplotlib                1.5.1               np111py35_0  
mkl                       11.3.3                        0  
numpy                     1.11.1                   py35_0  
openssl                   1.0.2i                        0  
pandas                    0.18.1              np111py35_0  
pip                       8.1.2                    py35_0  
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py35_0  
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py35_4  
python                    3.5.2                         0  
python-dateutil           2.5.3                    py35_0  
pytz                      2016.6.1                 py35_0  
qt                        4.8.7                         4  
readline                  6.2                           2  
requests                  2.11.1                   py35_0  
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np111py35_2  
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py35_0  
seaborn                   0.7.1                    py35_0  
setuptools                27.2.0                   py35_0  
sip                       4.18                     py35_0  
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0  
smart_open                1.3.4                    py35_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0  
xz                        5.2.2                         0  
zlib                      1.2.8                         3  

(data) Edwards-MacBook-Pro:~ mango$ ipython 
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import seaborn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-085c0287ecb5> in <module>()
----> 1 import seaborn

ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'

In [2]:
```

The same behavior occurs with gensim, so it is not just seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue.  Conda installs the [root] environment with ipython and jupyter.  If you create an env, those are not available by default.  So when creating and env, either be sure to list those packages explicitly, or clone root.  Cloning root may make a bulkier env and it may be less desirable for production, but better for a sandbox context.

I discovered this issue by trying the same test above with python and finding that my packages indicated that I was in the data env.  I then decided to try the Anaconda Navigator program with `conda install anaconda-navigator`.  While I like a cli, this GUI based program seems like a better way to manage packages.